# How to I factor these polynomial of degree $6$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working on a proof and I am at the part where I need to factor the following polynomial

$$4e_1^6+12e_1^5e_2-3e_1^4e_2^2-26e_1^3e_2^3-3e_1^2e_2^4+12e_1e_2^5+4e_2^6$$

How would I do that?

Comment: yes. i will updated the problem

Comment: Have you tried substituting to values to see if you can find something to divide against the polynomial? That would be my initial suggestion.

Comment: Why not throw it at [Sage](http://cloud.sagemath.com) or a similar program?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It turns out to factor very nicely into linear factors with small coefficients.  Try a few.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $e_1=e_2$, then the polynomial is identically zero. Similarly if $e_1=-2e_2$, and by symmetry likewise for $e_2=-2e_1$.